# Oracle APEX Interactive Grid Filter on Shuttle Columns APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex

APEX Interactive Grids have a nice OOTB feature for filtering columns as long as they are represented by text areas, or text fields or selects. As soon as you change them to multi-select or shuttle they are no longer filterable with the out of the box functionality.

Is there a workaround where one could create a custom filter perhaps with a dynamic action?

I just need to search for a string in the field.

Use case is a multi-value column that holds tags and I just want to find records that contain one of the tags.

This would be handy for prototyping where you don't want to create a tags table and many-to-many mappings etc.

I'm using APEX 19.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add a filter to a shuttle because the each row might contain more than one value (return/display value). So Apex internally won't know what to show when filtered.